# Concatenating two images in python but the color has been changed

Tags: python

Initially I tried to concatenating two images together in python and I implemented the following codes.

```
folderA = './folderA'
folderB = './folderB'
dest_path = './output'

splits = os.listdir(folderA)

for sp in splits:
    img_fold_A = os.path.join(folderA, sp)
    img_fold_B = os.path.join(folderB, sp)
    img_list = os.listdir(img_fold_A)
    num_imgs = len(img_list)
    img_fold_AB = os.path.join(dest_path, sp)
    if not os.path.isdir(img_fold_AB):
        os.makedirs(img_fold_AB)
    print('split = %s, number of images = %d' % (sp, num_imgs))
    for n in range(num_imgs):
        name_A = img_list[n]
        path_A = os.path.join(img_fold_A, name_A)
        name_B = name_A
        path_B = os.path.join(img_fold_B, name_B)
        if os.path.isfile(path_A) and os.path.isfile(path_B):
            name_AB = name_A
            path_AB = os.path.join(img_fold_AB, name_AB)
            im_A1 = Image.open(path_A)
            im_A = np.array(im_A1)
            im_B1 = Image.open(path_B)
            im_B = np.array(im_B1)
            im_AB = np.concatenate([im_A, im_B], 1)
            cv2.imwrite(path_AB, im_AB)
```

but I find out the concatenated images output resulted in the color changes.

May I know the reason why and how to avoid this phenomenon. Many thanks!

Comment: What kind of images are these?  Unless you're seeing compression/decompression artifacts, the colors shouldn't change.  What color changes do you see?  Note that PIL can concatenate images natively.  https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-pillow-concat-images/

Comment: Since you save the image with opencv. Instead of `Image.open()` you can read the image directly with `opencv` so that you don't have to worry about color mappings.

Comment: @YashvanderBamel Many thanks! Your solution works well in the situation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely because you're reading the image using Pillow/PIL which assumes the order of colors is red-green-blue but writing the image using OpenCV which assumes the order of colors is blue-green-red.

You can either do as the comment above suggests and [use PIL to concatenate the images directly and save the result](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-pillow-concat-images/), or, if you really want to use OpenCV to write the image, you can flip the color dimension using `im_AB  = im_AB[:, :, ::-1]` which should also work.